# Require JS, Loading Libraries through CDN fails

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn, amd

I have read the answer to this question [require js loading scripts from cdn fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751996/require-js-loading-scripts-from-cdn-fail). But in my case it does not help. I have a require JS setup and I want to use CDN to load my libraries. 
The Require JS documentation says below is the right way to load libs from CDN with a fallback to local files.

```
  requirejs.config({
    //To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports check.
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'lib/jquery'
        ]
    }
});


require(['jquery'], function ($) {
});
```

I am using the same method but I get an error instead, below is my code

```
    requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/app',

    waitSeconds: 0,

    paths: {

        'jquery': ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min','/assets/js/vendor/jquery'],
        'jqueryPjax': '/assets/js/vendor/jquery.pjax',
        'jqueryUI': '/assets/js/vendor/jquery-ui.min',

        'jqueryMousewheel': '/assets/js/jquery.mousewheel',
        'jScrollPane': '/assets/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min',

        'fastclick': '/assets/js/vendor/fastclick',

        'jquerySlidebars': '/assets/js/jquery.slidebars.min',

        'imagesLoaded': '/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min',
        'fancyBox': '/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack',
        'fancyBoxThumb': '/assets/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs',

        'text': '/assets/js/vendor/text',
        'chosen': '/assets/js/vendor/chosen',
        'bb': '/assets/js/vendor/backbone-min',
        'underscore': '/assets/js/vendor/underscore-min',
        'angular': '/assets/js/angular.min',


        'ventFactory': 'base/ventFactory',
        'util': 'base/util',
        'dom': 'base/dom',
        'actionHandler': 'base/actionHandler',
        'ajax': 'base/ajax'
    },

    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },

        'jqueryUI': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },

        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },

        'jqueryPjax': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.pjax'
        },

        'jqueryMousewheel': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.mousewheel'
        },

        'jScrollPane': {
            deps: ['jqueryMousewheel'],
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.jScrollPane'
        },

        'jquerySlidebars': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jquerySlidebars'
        },

        'fancyBox': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'fancyBox'
        },
        'fancyBoxThumb': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'fancyBox'],
            exports: 'fancyBoxThumb'
        },
        'chosen': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'chosen'
        }
    }

});

requirejs(['jquery', 'app'], function($, app) {
    $(function() {
        app.start();
    });
});
```

I have just made the changes for Jquery as of now and I am giving both CDN URL and local path but when I load my page I get an error

> TypeError: $el.siblings is not a function

Adding on
I am using Require JS for loading my libs but then at the production I am using almond, which combines all modules into one single file, so has this something to do with the error ?

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello Vishi, are you getting anything more than just that with the error? This could come from any file just yet...

Comment: @Salketer Hey thanks for the reply. Actually I am getting just this as an error. 
I am using Require JS for loading my libs but then at the production I am using almond, which combines all modules into one single file, so has this something to do with the error ?

Comment: Well, if the error only occurs on production, i'd look into almond (which I do not know). My guess is that almond will simply download the jQuery from CDN to package your JS so no big deal about CDN. If the error occurs even on pure RequireJS, the console always gives the file and line, this could be a starter point for your debug.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding on I am using Require JS for loading my libs but then at the production I am using almond, which combines all modules into one single file, so has this something to do with the error ?

Yes, it does. Almond cannot do dynamic loading. In other words, everything you want Almond to load must be into a single bundle of modules. You cannot use a CDN with Almond.

"No dynamic loading" is the first restriction in its [list of restrictions](https://github.com/jrburke/almond#restrictions).

Comment: Thanks for answering this louis. I some how missed the list of restrictions of almond I appreciate your help here